# Ссылка на файл с фтп сервера

Tags: ssh, администрирование, ftp

Я заказал отдельный сервер-хранилище на котором хотел размещать фалы, а ссылки на них публиковать на сайте который находится на другом сервере. Загрузил файлы на купленный сервер по фтп, но не могу разобраться как сделать так что бы можно было их скачивать пользователям... поставщик услуг дал только ID, Host, IP, логин и пароль. Написано, что подключатся я могу по SSH, Rsync, FTP, Samba. На вопросы как можно добраться до файлов не вводя логин и пароль к фтп, а просто по ip поставщик сказал что надо настроить сервер. Как это сделать я не понимаю...

Может есть какой то другой способ вывести ссылки на файлы и скрыть от пользователя логин и пароль от фтп?

Comment: вам вполне логично посоветовали настроить *ftp-сервер*. но если использование столь неудачного протокола для вас не критично, я бы посоветовал для отдачи файлов использовать протокол *http* и достаточно быстро и ненакладно справляющийся с такой задачей *http-сервер* **nginx**.

Comment: а нельзя как нибудь с php сделать так что бы можно было вывести ссылку на фаил с фтп ftp:// root:pass@194.135.95.151/a.png только что бы пользователь не видел логин и пароль? я в настройке серверов вообще ничего не понимаю и времени углубляться нет :(

Comment: так, чтобы «не увидел», можно. но в этом случае отдавать **содержимое** файлов пользователю будет именно ваш сайт, что, как я понял, для вас нежелательно.

Comment: "отдавать содержимое файлов пользователю будет именно ваш сайт" то есть это будет так, что сначала файл из того сервера будет загружаться на мой где лежит сайт? читал в мануале про функции php что то такое но думал что не так понял...

Comment: *сначала файл из того сервера будет загружаться на мой* — да, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: не, такой вариант не реален, на моем сервере где сайт нет столько места и трафик ограничен, а файлы большие... надо как то сервер настраивать значит, но как... нет никакого cpanel'я, подключился с WinSCP, там куча всякий файлов, конфигов каких то...

Comment: *нет столько места* — место не потребуется: ваш сайт будет всего лишь отдавать содержимое, загружая его со второй машины. *трафик ограничен* — а вот трафик потребуется. *нет никакого cpanel* — так это же замечательно! // но если вам нужно срочно, то лучше обратиться на какую-нибудь биржу фрилансеров.

Comment: с чего мне тогда начать? может могли бы дать ссылку на какой нибудь материал в тему? читал много но все какие то комманды, еоторые я даже не знаю куда вводить

Comment: начните с определения названия и версии дистрибутива, который установлен на сервере.

Comment: centos-6-x86_64-filer

Comment: поздравляю! вы собрали достаточно информации для того, чтобы либо воспользоваться любым поисковиком, либо задать вопрос на [ru.so]. удачи!

Answer (score 1):

решил свою проблему таким способом:

в файле конфигурации /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf установил anonymous_enable=YES и теперь могу давать ссылки на файлы в таком виде anonymous:anonymous@123.123.123.123/pub/file.png

Было бы отлично найти совет как сконфигурировать сервер для доступа по http, но не могу нагуглить...